# Bottom navigation issue on intent shifting

Tags: bottomnavigationview

I want to switch activities in bottom navigation. I have written all code correctly by following the proper steps. But when I am writing the switch function in bottom navigation item listener view, an unknown error is coming, even android studio is unable to suggest anything on the error. I tried changing values of menu.xml file and tried to recreate the whole concept multiple times its not working.

menu.xml:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/homeId"
    android:title="@string/menu_home"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_home_24"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/likeid"
    android:title="@string/menu_ito"
    android:icon="@drawable/itoic"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/walletId"
    android:title="@string/menu_wallet"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_account_balance_wallet_24"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/profileId"
    android:title="@string/menu_profile"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_account_circle_24"/>
```

Navigation bar:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/round_corners"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    app:itemIconSize="30dp"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/item_selector"
    app:itemRippleColor="@android:color/transparent"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
    app:menu="@menu/menu" >
    
</com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>`
```

Error is here in this main Java code:

```
navigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
navigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.homeId);

  navigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener(item -> {
       switch (item.getItemId()) {

           case R.id.homeId:
               return true;
           case R.id.walletId:
               startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                       WalletActivity.class));
               overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
               return true;
           case R.id.profileId:
               startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                       ProfileActivity.class));
               overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
               return true;
           case R.id.likeId:
               startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                       likeActivity.class));
               overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
               return true;
       }
       return false;
   });
```

I have tried searching on the internet to resolve this issue but it seems that the issue is internal and I am missing something in the term of SDK or Project integration. I have gone thoroughly every document available on Android studio website about bottom navigation but wasn't able to find what is wrong with my code. I'm new to Android development.

Comment: what type of error give, provide that error in qursion